Please help identify this Micron chip
Could someone please help identify this Micron chip (9FFID NW939). I need to know the exact model to specify the device in a Phyton ChipProg.  It's a BGA type.  Thank you.


The Micron FBGA and component marking decoder shows:



FBGA Code
Part Number




NW939
MT29F8G08ADBFAH4-AAT:F



I can't seem to find a datasheet on the Micron website.
The Mouser page MT29F8G08ADBFAH4-AAT:F gives the lifecycle as Obsolete and the description is NAND Flash SLC 8G 1GX8 FBGA DDP.
While the Mouser and other distributor websites claim to have a datasheet, it only contains a screenshot of a Micron webpage.

Thank you so much.
